# Should I create a stored function/procedure or keep the query?

Tags: sql, algorithm, db2, logic

This may be the wrong spot to ask this question so please forgive me if it is.

So I have a DB2 query that is 400 lines long but it does quite a few separate calculations to determine if a customer is profitable or not with their LTL shipments by lane and by terminal/delivery location.

My question is generally speaking would it be faster to continue to do this in a query form or pass some of the algorithm through a stored function? It is running the OR report by line item so there could be thousands of lines/bills per customer for any given time period.

I guess I am just looking for some advice from you beautiful people that have a different perspective or more experience than me.

Thanks.

--EDIT--
I am trying to increase speed, when I run it for 1 customer its fast enough but when I run it company wide it takes about a half hour for a month of data(roughly 40k bills).
It really only deals with 4 tables, mostly just calls for 1 column of data. At its widest point its about 40 columns wide, but that could be condensed, i just like to be able to see the calculations in line before they are combined and summed up in a cleaner format. I do make use of a With Loop as() and then just mine that temp table for the final output.

Comment: My 2 cents: If it ain't broke, why fix it?

Comment: Question in my opinion is too broad.  Are you trying to improve performance?  improve maintainability?  keep performance but improve maintainability what?  I'm a don't fix what's not broke kinda guy too but in down times I do look for ways to simplify code improve performance and mintainability.

Comment: The answer to the question depends on factors that you omit from your question. How many tables, how many rows in the tables/in the result-set, what is the access plan, is the access plan optimal, what are the performance-requirements etc.

Comment: I updated my question for you guys if you wanted to chime in as well, I always looking for suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as architecture, it could be good to **break down complexity** where you can into smaller more maintainable modules. Use stored functions or stored procedures where it makes sense. This gives you as well, a bit of a *re-usable code base* as far as *SQL*. USE a **`JOIN`** like `INNER JOIN, LEFT OUTER JOIN, FULL OUTER JOIN` and such to pull your results together, as this will be *faster* than plumbing through the **line items** in a **`FOR`** loop and **`CURSOR`** for instance. Proper *Indexing* can effect performance as well. Where you can get into trouble though with this approach is having nested stored procedures getting called millions of times. There is just a small overhead for each context change or procedure call. If you need to, store results in local temp tables and join back to them for performance gains, if the logic is pulling a lot of results and you have multi-staged data, etc. Hope these tips help.

Comment: That's the direction kind of wanting to go, for ease and efficiency so I am glad you broke out the steps with your suggestion, it helps loads thanks.

Comment: I've seen cases where short queries (such as 400 lines) were made into stored procedures and the result was dreadful performance (caused by poor skills, using java procedures, failing to properly test etc).  So while motivations can be flawless, it's the eventual outcome that actually counts.

Comment: I agree mao. My problem with SQL is how large the code can become compared to *Object Oriented* code for instance. Separating out the code into *procs* can help with overall understanding of the different needs, and reduce code size of the main entry point *proc* or calling SQL statement. Procs are great for reducing redundant code. I typically want to use databases purely as *data stores* though. I think of them more as a repository for instance, and do much of the Business Logic in the middle tier. This way if my application switches technologies for data storage I am not redeveloping logic.